# Generating a formula

Tags: math, formula

```
x = n
while x > 0:
   x = x // 2
```

Let `x_k` denote the variable `x` after k iterations. How do I find `x_k`?

Is it floor(n / 2)^k?

Answer (score 0):

For integers you can use right shift

```
x_k = n >> k
```

If you want to use division (note k power is not applied to n)

```
x_k = n // (2**k)
```